# iOS and dealing with large database

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, database, ios4

I have a very large database, and I am trying to populate a table view in the most efficient/logical way possible.

I'm leaning toward using an object to store the information in.  Any ideas of an more efficient way of doing this?  Would core data be better?

Comment: How are you populating the table view now?

Comment: I'm trying to populate the table from an object

Comment: How big does the SQLite database get to be?  Are you using transaction control to speed things along?

Comment: @HotLicks I don't believe there is a size limit for the database.  I just query the database, and store in some kind of data object, which right now is an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, for 100K rows, that sounds like Core Data to me. (If necessary, you could write a little app to run on the Simulator that reads in the data and saves it to a Core Data database you'd then include in the app bundle.)

Comment: Although, converting my large database to Core Data seems a little difficult, this is most likely the right solution, and possible the most efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Core Data with NSFetchedResultsController will be an efficient way to get that data out of the CD entity and into a UITableView.  I have dealt with record sets up to 4500 rows, but never something that large.

One suggestion is to set the fetchLimit down low on any filtering methods